# I got a weird issue in Emacs Backtrace

Tags: emacs, dot-emacs

I'm using Emacs 24.3.1

I'm editing .emacs file, but something comes up, when I try to byte-compile it, the Message buffer says:

```
Load: symbols's value as variale is void:
```

Note the end of line, NOTHING, there is no variable such as *custom-theme-load-path*, is pretty weird.

Then in Terminal: emacs --debug-init, the Backtrace shows:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable )
eval-buffer(#<buffer *load*> nil "/home/chz.emacs" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 35761
load-with-code-cinversion...
...long lines comtaining my plugins...
command-line()
normal-top-level()
```

But when I M-x goto-char 35761, that line is a comment line, pretty weird...

When I added the cebet config in .emacs, the error came up, the configuration detail is in  http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-devenv/EmacsCedet.html

What should I do to get rid of the error??? Please Help!!

Comment: Just bisect issue - first comment out the second half of `~/.emacs`. If the problem is gone, that means
it was in the second half, if not - it's in the first half. Continue until you find the line with
the error.

Comment: @abo-abo I know the wrong part, the issue came up after I added that part, but when I commented out line by line, it came up at a specific line, after commenting it, it was still there, When I commented out the whole part, the error was still there. Now I don't know what to do.

Comment: Since the error doesn't say much, just show the minimal example of faulty code.

Comment: Refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16798962/getting-started-with-cedet/16912612#16912612 for minimal CEDET setup

Comment: @abo-abo Thank you for your reply, I've deleted all the cedet related codes(even my cedet related codes are all commented out), then I add the configuration line by line, by-compile after adding every line, it is totally fine now.